# How to set Mode of H263 when use MediaCodec in Android?

Tags: android-mediacodec, webrtc-android

When adding H.263 encoding support to WebRTC, I find that the RTP packets I send are in Mode A, but the packets received from the peer are in Mode B, resulting in an inability to display properly on both sides. How can I set the mode when using MediaCodec? Can I use MediaFormat to achieve this?

The way to set H263 mode when use mediacodec